# A discontinuous function at every point in $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

> Suppose you are given a measurable set $E\subset[0,1]$ such that for any nonempty open sub-interval $I$ in $[0,1]$, both sets $E \cap I$ and $E^c \cap I$ have positive measure. Then, for the function $f:=\chi_E$, where $\chi_E$ is characteristic function, show that whenever $g(x)=f(x)$ a.e. in $x$, then $g$ must be discontinuous at every point in $[0,1]$ .

I think we can take advantage of the problem of making a measurable subset $E ⇢ [0, 1]$ such that for every sub-interval $I$, both $E \ I$ and $I - E$ have positive measure by taking a Cantor-type subset of $[0, 1]$ with positive measure and on each sub-interval of the complement of this set, and construct another such set, and so on. I don't know if I am right.

Comment: Dose not that mean  $E$ cannot contain an interval since if there exits $I \subset E$ Then we get $E^c \cap I = \phi$ which has a zero measure.

Comment: That's correct, $E$ should not contain any intervals. Nor should it's complement.

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't require any constructions. Take $x\in (0,1)$. Then for any open interval $I$ around $x$, we know that $f$ takes the value 1 on a positive measure set, and the value 0 on a positive measure set. Then because $g=f$ a.e. the same is true for $g$. So $g$ cannot be continuous at $x$.

The boundary points work more or less the same, just using the open intervals $(0,\varepsilon)$ and $(1-\varepsilon,1)$.

Comment: @Zach_Stone Thanks, But it is not proved for function $f$. It is not a solution, just restating the problem statement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What assumption did I make that I shouldn't have? Or is there a jump in the logic?

Comment: @ You are assuming this is true for $f$, and with that you prove it for $g$. We want to prove it also for $f$.

Comment: I didn't assume it for $f$. All I said about $f$ was that on each interval $I$, it takes the values $0$ and $1$ each on a set of positive measure (notably non-empty). It should be pretty clear that this implies discontinuity everywhere. Define two sequences approaching your point $x$ so that $f(a_n)=1$ and $f(b_n)=0$ for all $n$. This step is missing from the proof, but you should be able to fill in the details.